# BMI Calculator with GUI boxes

Tags: java, user-interface

So I have an assignment where I have to create a BMI calculator with input and output boxes. 
The problem I have is that it gives me NaN as an answer. I've searched this site and others and come to find out that the problem is this:

```
 private static double input() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return 0;
}
```

If I change the value, it gives me a number but not the number I'm looking for. Everything else works, it's just the bit with the output that's bugging me.

```
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.*;

public class BMI_GUI {
private static String input;

public static void main(String[] args){

    double vikt;
    double langd;
    double bmi;

    setInput(showInputDialog("Din vikt i kg: "));
    vikt = input();

    setInput(showInputDialog("Din längd i m (med ett komma): "));
    langd = input();

    bmi = (vikt / (langd*langd));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Din BMI är " + bmi);

    System.out.println("BMI Värden\n");
    System.out.println("Undervikt: Under 18.5");
    System.out.println("Normal: 18.5 - 24.9");
    System.out.println("Övervikt: 25 - 29.9");
    System.out.println("Fetma: 30 eller över");

    }

    private static double input() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
    }

    public static String getInput() {
    return input;
    }

    public static void setInput(String input) {
    BMI_GUI.input = input;
    }

}
```

Comment: You're dividing `weight` by 0.

Comment: "Everything else works" - well not really. You're not actually using any input from the user. Heck, you're not even using `vikt` and `langd` - you're using the `weight` and `length` variables which are just hard-coded to be 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems here. You are not refering to the variables you want to refer to in your calculation (`length` and `width`), and you are calling an empty `input()` method, which does nothing for you so you can get rid of it completely. Same goes for the `getInput()` method. Since you're already reading in the input into the static `input` string of the `BMI_GUI`, just parse it for a double. This works, but ideally you should add error checking as well - what if you enter a `String` instead of a number that can be parsed to a `double`? You should handle that `NumberFormatException` - maybe re-ask the user for the same input that was just being asked for.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double bmi = 0.0;

    setInput(showInputDialog("Your weight in kg: "));
    double weight = Double.parseDouble(input);

    setInput(showInputDialog("Your length in m (with a comma): "));
    double length = Double.parseDouble(input);

    bmi = (weight / (length * length));
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably want

```
private static double input() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return Double.parseDouble(getInput());
}
```